# Writing a relatively simple Boolean function as a Lambda Expression in F#

Tags: lambda, f#

I created a BST using F#, including a `count` function that takes a generic Boolean  `evaluate` function as a parameter. This `evaluate` function tells `count` which leaves to tally: for example if you wanted to count all the leaves you would pass it an `evaluate` function that returns `true` if the leaf exists and `false` if it does not.

All the functions are working as intended, but have hit a road block. I need to create an `evenCount` function that counts all leaves containing even-values, and I need to implement it as a call to `count` passing a lambda function as the `evaluate` parameter. But I can't figure out how to translate a function that tests if an integer is even into a lambda expression.

Here are the basic functions/definitions:

```
type BST =
| Empty
| TreeNode of int * BST * BST

let nodeTestBase = function
    | Empty -> false
    | _ -> true

let nodeTestEven = function
    | Empty -> false
    | TreeNode(value, left, right) ->
        if (value % 2 = 0) then true
        else false

let rec insert value tree =
    match tree with
    | Empty -> TreeNode(value, Empty, Empty)
    | TreeNode(hd, left, right) as node ->
        if hd = value then node
        elif value < hd then TreeNode(hd, insert value left, right)
        else TreeNode(hd, left, insert value right)

let count func tree =
    let rec loop tally = function
        | Empty -> tally
        | TreeNode(value, left, right) as node ->
            if func node then 1 + (loop 0 left) + (loop 0 right)
            else 0
    loop 0 tree
```

I need to write the entirety of `nodeTestEven` as a lambda expression in a call to `count`. ie:

```
let evenCount = 
    count "lambda expression" tree_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type BST =
| Empty
| TreeNode of int * BST * BST

let nodeTestBase = function
  | Empty -> false
  | _ -> true

let nodeTestEven = function
  | Empty -> false
  | TreeNode(value, left, right) ->
      if (value % 2 = 0) then true
      else false

let count f (t:BST) : int =
  let rec count f (t:BST) : int = 
    match t with
    | Empty -> 0                                                     // left or right could be empty (see case 3).
    | TreeNode(n,left,right) -> (if f n then 1 else 0) + (count f left) + (count f right)                // a leaf, so test and count.
    | TreeNode(_,left,right)  -> (count f left) + (count f right)    // count left and right branches
  count f t

let count2 f (t:BST) : int =
  let rec count f (t:BST) : int = 
    match t with
    | Empty -> 0                                                     // left or right could be empty (see case 3).
    // *** pass in predicate f : (BST -> bool) to decide
    // *** when to count the node. i.e. function takes a
    // ***  BST and returns a bool
    // see pattern matching docs on use of & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching        
    | TreeNode(_,left,right) & x when f x -> 1 + (count f left) + (count f right)
    | TreeNode(_,left,right)  -> (count f left) + (count f right)    // count left and right branches
  count f t
```

test data

```
let t = TreeNode(1,
          TreeNode(2,
            TreeNode(10,
              TreeNode(12,Empty,Empty),
              TreeNode(14,Empty,Empty)),
            TreeNode(20,
              TreeNode(22,Empty,Empty),
              TreeNode(24,Empty,Empty))),
          TreeNode(5,
            TreeNode(3,Empty,Empty),
            TreeNode(7,Empty,Empty)
          ))

let even n = n % 2 = 0
let odd n = n % 2 = 1
```

**tests**

predefined

```
count even t
count odd t
```

inline

```
count (fun n-> n%2=0) t
count (fun n-> n%2=1) t
```

entire node

```
count2 nodeTestEven t
```

entire node using inline style

```
count2 (function 
        | Empty -> false 
        | TreeNode(value, left, right) -> (value % 2 = 0))
        t
```

test entire node using **fun** inline style

```
count2 (fun node->node |> function 
        | Empty -> false 
        | TreeNode(value, left, right) -> (value % 2 = 0))
        t
```

match version

```
count2 (fun node->
          match node with
          | Empty -> false 
          | TreeNode(value, left, right) -> (value % 2 = 1)) 
       t
```

Comment: This is good stuff, but the requirements specifically state that I have to use a lambda expression in the function call to count. Your solution is more or less what I already have just shifted around a bit.

I need to figure out how to write the `nodeTestEven` expression using the `fun` keyword, in-line, in a function call to count.

Comment: as per comment.

Comment: I take it @user3776749, that count2 does the inline stuff that you need. See the "& x when f x -> 1" bit specifically, and the extra tests that utilise count2 which has a signature of (BST -> bool) -> BST -> int. We're just passing in an inline function to act on a node. Hope that helps. Check out Pattern Matching. Perhaps Active Patterns are useful, too. link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching. It's easy to miss the relevance of the "&" in the pattern matching docs.

Comment: This, and the linked resources have been immensely helpful, thank you. The purpose of this assignment was certainly to gain a better understanding of basic F# programming principles, and these examples have really helped me see how things work from different angles.

Comment: So I just ran your suggestions, and running count `(fun n-> n%2=0) t` exactly as you have it set up returns 4 instead of 7 which it should. There's something goofy with the tally somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I thought you just wanted to look at leaf nodes. The pattern match TreeNode(_,Empty,Empty) was the culprit. So I changed this (see above). You will now get the count of 7.